# How to change a table in CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-table, media-queries

I want to change the order of my table, because of a media query.

in my HTML, my code looks like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
     <td>date1</td>
    <td>place1</td>
    <td>ticket1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>date2</td>
    <td>place2</td>
    <td>ticket2</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

which looks like this:
[image]

now because I want to change it up for a different screen size. 
It has to look like this.

[image]

How do I do this in CSS?

Comment: use a mediaquerie to set your breakpoint  to reset td  display : possible : `@media screen and (max-width : 500px) {td{display:block} }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply update the display of the table elements:

```css
tbody,tr,td {  /* you can also include "table" if you want full width table */
  display:block;
}
td {
  border:1px solid;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
     <td>date1</td>
    <td>place1</td>
    <td>ticket1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>date2</td>
    <td>place2</td>
    <td>ticket2</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 3):

here is the easiest solution using a small amount of css and flexbox

```css
tr {

    font-size: 5em;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    tr {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}
```

```html
    <table>
        <tr>
         <td>date1</td>
        <td>place1</td>
        <td>ticket1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>date2</td>
        <td>place2</td>
        <td>ticket2</td>
      </tr>
     </table>
```

**mobile view:**

[image]

**PC VIEW**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```css
tr td{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr >
     <td>date1</td>
    <td>place1</td>
    <td>ticket1</td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not request your display to single view, you should always use `mediaquery` if you using it for responsive screen, below snippet helps to create a different view based on screen responsivness.

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/cs9p8067/5/) using `mediaquery`.

```css
table,
tr,
td {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width:300px) {
  /* any other screen size */
  table tr>* {
    display: inline;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>date1</td>
    <td>place1</td>
    <td>ticket1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>date2</td>
    <td>place2</td>
    <td>ticket2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```